# Delegates in C# and how do I attach them to controls in visual studio?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm new to C# and delegates, however, from what I've gathered, they say if this event happened run this method. But in Visual Studio (community 2017), I can't figure out where/how I am meant to go about defining/attaching them.

I'd appreciate an answer as I'm trying to go about switching a program I've previously written in Python over to C#.

I've looked through documentation, I've looked over questions already asked here, and none of them seem to give me the information I'm after.

Comment: You should most likely get started here: [Delegates (c# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: I have already looked at that. If I found my answer elsewhere, I wouldn't be asking here. To clarify, I'm looking for where do I attach delegates in Visual Studio, because I can't find anywhere that looks even remotely similar to the reference book I am using. It tells me to use "+=" to attach a delegate to a control, however, I can't find where the control is using this IDE.

Comment: What type of project are you working on? If the book tells you to use `+=`, that's done on a .cs file. Perhaps add a screenshot of the file you are working with?

Comment: It is aWindows Form Application. Apparently I can't link to pastebin.com, but all the code from the files is in the following links: https://pastebin.com/C70YStby, https://pastebin.com/as3YJtPW, https://pastebin.com/ernJNnGu (Form1.cs, Form1.Designer.cs,Program.cs)

Comment: Where do you want to use them? Line 159 of your designer file has one, for example. I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to link up events?

Comment: Whilst yes, there is a control there, the file specifies that I should not edit it within the code editor, leading to the question where do I attach a delegate to a control?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the control properties and use the events ([lightning bolt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kexM7.png)) panel?

Comment: I did not see that, sorry. Thanks for the help. Solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add delegates (in this case they're typically called "event handlers") to UI controls in WinForms, you should:

1. Select the control in the visual designer
2. Look at the Properties windows
3. Click the lightning bolt to view the events.
4. Either double-click the blank space next to an event to auto-generate a handler, or single-click and select an existing handler from the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Read up on "events" and delegates. You are actually adding a delegate to a predefined event when you use the += operator. Then, when the event is "raised", all the functions encapsulated by the delegates added to the event (if any) are called. It's the .NET implementation of the "publish/subscribe" or "observer" pattern. When you add a delegate representing a form's Btn1_Clicked method to a button instance's Clicked event, your form's handler(the method) is subscribing to that event.

Comment: @flydog57 Indeed :-)

Comment: Thanks, I get the question was written really poorly. I'm new to C# and Visual Studio. I appreciate the help.